# How Different is a Car's Bluetooth from phone Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm developing an application which makes use of a car's Bluetooth but I need to identify if a certain Bluetooth device is a car's Bluetooth. Is there a way to differentiate between Bluetooth devices other than the Bluetooth profiles supported by them.

Comment: Why do you care, if the device provides the same profiles a car would, why can't you just treat it the same. (and no there will be nothing other than the presented profiles to determine the device type)

Comment: @hardillb, Its a part of my business logic for user profiling NOT A BLUETOOTH PROFILE. Hence I would want to know if a certain Bluetooth device is recognized how to differentiate it based on its properties.

Comment: Yes, but what characteristics do you think a car will have that make it different to say a Bleutooth speaker?

Comment: That is exactly the reason I am seeking out for an answer I'm still doing some research will post it if I'm at a solid answer.